# Laravel 4 with Ember App

Tags: php, ember.js, laravel

I am creating a web application. I am fairly accustomed to Laravel and how it functions. I would like to know how I incorporate Ember into the Laravel setup. I am guessing public folder, but when I use Yeoman to install Ember into the public it involves the node_modules and gruntfile. My question is should all this be in the public folder (any security concerns?)

Some people say it is not good to mix the two. I would like multiple single page views so it makes sense. Plus it is a good challenge to get stuck into. I have researched any answers and had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your script files in your public folder, otherwise the clients browser wouldn't be able to fetch and use them. No security concerns there. That includes grunt, bower or any other files (if it happens that you need them in your production server).

We at work use Laravel and Ember. Ember is our true front end and Laravel is our true back end. It is a **very** good idea to use them together. It's also a good idea to start with multiple apps so you don't get overwhelmed in no time. In time, you can evolve to one huge app and/or you'll start writing components and mixins you can reuse across your apps.

Just a note: I use a combination of bootstrapped data (json_encoded in .blade views) and data fetched from the server via getJSON (I don't currently use Ember Data because is not production ready yet)

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Couldn't think of a better combination of frameworks. Thanks for the insight.